# KeyRingBasedDataProtector: unrepresentable DateTime

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm running into a problem with an ASPNET5/MVC6/DNX core site I'm building. It's supposed to require all users to be authenticated. It uses EF7 as a datastore, and user accounts/claims are built around the "default" EF7 user classes.

I've configured the security in startup.cs as follows:

```
    public void ConfigureServices( IServiceCollection services )
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(o =>
        {
            // configure identity options
            o.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            o.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            o.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            o.Password.RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false;
            o.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
        })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        // require authenticated users who have been validated (i.e., have a 'user' claim)
        AuthorizationPolicy authPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .RequireClaim("user")
            .Build();

        services.AddMvc( x=>
        {
            x.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(authPolicy));
        });

        // Add application services.
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();

        services.Configure<SiteConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("SiteConfig"));

        services.AddDataProtection();

        // have to avoid setting a file path when we're invoked by dnx
        if( (HostEnvironment != null) && (HostEnvironment.WebRootPath != null ) )
            services.ConfigureDataProtection(configure =>
            {
                string pathToCryptoKeys = Path.Combine(HostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "dp_keys");
                configure.PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(pathToCryptoKeys));
                configure.SetDefaultKeyLifetime(TimeSpan.MaxValue);
            });
    }
```

The site loads fine. But before the first page appears (which should be a login page) it crashes with the following error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> ArgumentOutOfRangeException: The added or subtracted value results in
>   an un-representable DateTime. Parameter name: t
>   System.DateTime.op_Addition(DateTime d, TimeSpan t)
>
> CryptographicException: An error occurred while trying to encrypt the
>   provided data. Refer to the inner exception for more information.
>   Microsoft.AspNet.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Protect(Byte[]
>   plaintext)

It looks like I've failed to configure, or misconfigured, something in the cryptographic arena. But I'm not sure what.

Comment: was a solution ever discovered for this issue?  I am experiencing the same problem :(

Comment: Sorry, but it's been so long that I don't recall if I solved the problem or just eliminated some functionality. FWIW, my current, working solution doesn't use AuthorizationPolicy.

Comment: Thanks Mark.  I will find the solution to this one, and let you know what I find.